# Adding annotation/label to OCI container-image without creating the container first

Tags: docker, podman, buildah, container-image

For adding some annotations/labels to a image, we first have to create the container from the image, and then we can add some annotations/labels using [buildah-config](https://www.mankier.com/1/buildah-config): `buildah-config [options] containerID`

But this requires first creating a container from image, then adding the required annotation/label, and then committing the changes back to an image.

But creating a container just for making some small change to the image configuration seems a unnecessary step which would take additional time and memory.

Is there a better way to add annotations/labels to a image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an image on a registry (or in an OCI Layout structure on the filesystem) there are various tools to modify that image. From [go-containerregistry](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry) (by Google), there's `crane mutate`:

```bash
$ crane mutate --help
Modify image labels and annotations. The container must be pushed to a registry, and the manifest is updated there.

Usage:
  crane mutate [flags]

Flags:
  -a, --annotation stringToString   New annotations to add (default [])
      --append strings              Path to tarball to append to image
      --cmd strings                 New cmd to set
      --entrypoint strings          New entrypoint to set
  -e, --env stringToString          New envvar to add (default [])
  -h, --help                        help for mutate
  -l, --label stringToString        New labels to add (default [])
  -t, --tag string                  New tag to apply to mutated image. If not provided, push by digest to the original image repository.

Global Flags:
      --insecure            Allow image references to be fetched without TLS
      --platform platform   Specifies the platform in the form os/arch[/variant][:osversion] (e.g. linux/amd64). (default all)
  -v, --verbose             Enable debug logs
```

And from [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) (by myself), there's `regctl image mod`:

```bash
$ regctl image mod --help
EXPERIMENTAL: Applies requested modifications to an image

Usage:
  regctl image mod <image_ref> [flags]

Flags:
      --annotation stringArray          set an annotation (name=value) (default )
      --annotation-base stringArray     set base image annotations (image/name:tag,sha256:digest) (default )
      --buildarg-rm string              delete a build arg (default "")
      --buildarg-rm-regex string        delete a build arg with a regex value (default "")
      --config-time-max string          max timestamp for a config (default "")
      --create string                   Create tag
      --data-max stringArray            sets or removes descriptor data field (size in bytes) (default )
      --expose-add stringArray          add an exposed port (default )
      --expose-rm stringArray           delete an exposed port (default )
      --external-urls-rm                remove external url references from layers (first copy image with "--include-external") (default )
      --file-tar-time-max stringArray   max timestamp for contents of a tar file within a layer (default )
  -h, --help                            help for mod
      --label stringArray               set an label (name=value) (default )
      --label-to-annotation             set annotations from labels (default )
      --layer-rm-created-by string      delete a layer based on history (created by string is a regex) (default "")
      --layer-rm-index uint             delete a layer from an image (index begins at 0) (default )
      --layer-strip-file string         delete a file or directory from all layers (default "")
      --layer-time-max string           max timestamp for a layer (default "")
      --rebase                          rebase an image using OCI annotations (default )
      --rebase-ref string               rebase an image with base references (base:old,base:new) (default "")
      --replace                         Replace tag (ignored when "create" is used)
      --time-max string                 max timestamp for both the config and layers (default "")
      --to-oci                          convert to OCI media types (default )
      --volume-add stringArray          add a volume definition (default )
      --volume-rm stringArray           delete a volume definition (default )

Global Flags:
      --logopt stringArray   Log options
      --user-agent string    Override user agent
  -v, --verbosity string     Log level (debug, info, warn, error, fatal, panic) (default "warning")
```

For example:

```bash
$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest
Name:        localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest
MediaType:   application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
Digest:      sha256:bc41182d7ef5ffc53a40b044e725193bc10142a1243f395ee852a8d9730fc2ad     
                                                                                                         
Manifests:                     
                   
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:1304f174557314a7ed9eddb4eab12fed12cb0cd9809e4c28f29af86979a3c870  
  Digest:    sha256:1304f174557314a7ed9eddb4eab12fed12cb0cd9809e4c28f29af86979a3c870     
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/amd64     
              
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:5da989a9a3a08357bc7c00bd46c3ed782e1aeefc833e0049e6834ec1dcad8a42
  Digest:    sha256:5da989a9a3a08357bc7c00bd46c3ed782e1aeefc833e0049e6834ec1dcad8a42
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm/v6                    
                          
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:0c673ee68853a04014c0c623ba5ee21ee700e1d71f7ac1160ddb2e31c6fdbb18
  Digest:    sha256:0c673ee68853a04014c0c623ba5ee21ee700e1d71f7ac1160ddb2e31c6fdbb18
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm/v7                                                                                
             
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:ed73e2bee79b3428995b16fce4221fc715a849152f364929cdccdc83db5f3d5c
  Digest:    sha256:ed73e2bee79b3428995b16fce4221fc715a849152f364929cdccdc83db5f3d5c
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/arm64
                          
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:1d96e60e5270815238e999aed0ae61d22ac6f5e5f976054b24796d0e0158b39c
  Digest:    sha256:1d96e60e5270815238e999aed0ae61d22ac6f5e5f976054b24796d0e0158b39c
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/386
                 
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:fa30af02cc8c339dd7ffecb0703cd4a3db175e56875c413464c5ba46821253a8
  Digest:    sha256:fa30af02cc8c339dd7ffecb0703cd4a3db175e56875c413464c5ba46821253a8
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/ppc64le
             
  Name:      localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest@sha256:c2046a6c3d2db4f75bfb8062607cc8ff47896f2d683b7f18fe6b6cf368af3c60
  Digest:    sha256:c2046a6c3d2db4f75bfb8062607cc8ff47896f2d683b7f18fe6b6cf368af3c60
  MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
  Platform:  linux/s390x
                                                    
$ regctl image config localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest                                                
{    
  "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.47374331Z",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "config": {                                                                                            
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ]
  },
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:994393dc58e7931862558d06e46aa2bb17487044f670f310dffe1d24e4d1eec7"
    ]
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.274069586Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2a949686d9886ac7c10582a6c29116fd29d3077d02755e87e111870d63607725 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.47374331Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]
}

$ regctl image mod localhost:5000/library/alpine:latest \
    --create mod --to-oci \
    --annotation new.annotation=value \
    --label some.label=1234
localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod

$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod
Name:             localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod
MediaType:        application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
Digest:           sha256:5e1e3ed73857b08895477418bdd2b73cc9536886d84d98ef986eacca08e100ea
Annotations:      
  new.annotation: value
                   
Manifests:        
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:f457cc17d630de3464ee3cd796fe83527a3daf3d1d28f710ed65b7162c29a632
  Digest:         sha256:f457cc17d630de3464ee3cd796fe83527a3daf3d1d28f710ed65b7162c29a632
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/amd64
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:a442ff642289b8b9a4268451c29fc7ce8f3685ba08b32adb1fd9ddd36b4f46e4
  Digest:         sha256:a442ff642289b8b9a4268451c29fc7ce8f3685ba08b32adb1fd9ddd36b4f46e4
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/arm/v6
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:003520fdc1749c2bd2d49781b24ae6937a219576541d20754124c24467e75ffc
  Digest:         sha256:003520fdc1749c2bd2d49781b24ae6937a219576541d20754124c24467e75ffc
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/arm/v7
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:624a37e9b645a5286db52b2a8536f43bb64e0352fa10e847f4f049b4773046fc
  Digest:         sha256:624a37e9b645a5286db52b2a8536f43bb64e0352fa10e847f4f049b4773046fc
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/arm64
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:9fbcc84ca534fa1d3b0047226860e39321da082615bdef03946edd5225952217
  Digest:         sha256:9fbcc84ca534fa1d3b0047226860e39321da082615bdef03946edd5225952217
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/386
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:08246b80173b3ace4446aca1e26406d1cef1eaea29126ab3ebe964e0fbba4dd9
  Digest:         sha256:08246b80173b3ace4446aca1e26406d1cef1eaea29126ab3ebe964e0fbba4dd9
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/ppc64le
                   
  Name:           localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod@sha256:945b2dab97c5518c276e53df551871ec089736f3abc7fe62003923b04ed9bcb5
  Digest:         sha256:945b2dab97c5518c276e53df551871ec089736f3abc7fe62003923b04ed9bcb5
  MediaType:      application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:       linux/s390x

$ regctl image config localhost:5000/library/alpine:mod                                                   
{
  "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.47374331Z",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "config": {
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ],
    "Labels": {
      "some.label": "1234"
    }
  },
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:994393dc58e7931862558d06e46aa2bb17487044f670f310dffe1d24e4d1eec7"
    ]
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.274069586Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2a949686d9886ac7c10582a6c29116fd29d3077d02755e87e111870d63607725 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.47374331Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does it work for index ae well?

Comment: @QasimSarfraz yes: https://github.com/regclient/regclient/pull/457

Comment: That is looking great. I was trying with buildx imagetools and crane. Both of the tools doesn't support adding annotations to image index.

Answer (score 0):

But if you modify an image in any way the image digest will change and thus you have a different image.